# JetBrains Resharper Line break when doing silent code cleanup

Tags: c#, resharper, jetbrains-ide

Whenever I perform silent cleanup my methods format like this:

```
public void MyMethod(
     IEnumerable<IPaymentMethod> paymentMethods,
     IPaymentMethod expected,
     bool isDirectBill) {
```

and I want it to format like so:

```
public void MyMethod(
     IEnumerable<IPaymentMethod> paymentMethods,
     IPaymentMethod expected,
     bool isDirectBill) 
{
```

For the life of me i can't find the settings for this

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to this problem? (A better statement of which would be "Resharper code cleanup reformats code as it damn pleases instead of exactly as the editor does it")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to ReSharper `Options -> Code Editing -> Code Cleanup`. Check the profile used for the silent clean-up (on bottom) and make sure `Reformat Code` option is checked for this profile.
2. Then go to `Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout` and check preferences for a method declaration.